# HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure with error code: 0x80070057

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have try to run the command dotnet MVCWebAPI.dll and it's working fine i can able to call api also.

When try to publish in iis 10.0.xx get the below error:

HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
Common causes of this issue:

```
The application process failed to start
The application process started but then stopped
The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port
```

Troubleshooting steps:

```
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
```

When open event viewer get the below message:

Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/DEFAULT WEB SITE' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\' failed to start process with commandline ' ', ErrorCode = '0x80070057' : 0.

Below is my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments="./MVCWebAPI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="./logs/stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: 1) Have you installed the IIS hosting bundle? 2) If so, did you restart the server afterwards? 3) Did you run `dotnet MVCWebAPI.dll` on the same server your app in IIS is on?

Comment: @ChrisPratt 1) Have you installed the IIS hosting bundle?- Yes Install 2) If so, did you restart the server afterwards? - Yes 3) Did you run dotnet MVCWebAPI.dll on the same server your app in IIS is on - Yes.

Comment: @Khushali if any package missing then dotnet command also not work.

Comment: Finally found the issue is need to provide full path for "dotnet" and also need to set arguments = "MVCWebAPI.dll" in this if use ./ then it will point the root directory.